# comparing column values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on multiple tables in PostgreSQL and I want to compare the column values of two tables but one of them is written differently here is how

[image]

[image]

it's the same values but one of them starts with three Zeros.
I've tried this

```
select * from table1, table2
where table1.projectid=table2.project_id and operating_unit= 'USA'
```

I even tries to replace '=' with 'IN' but both return an empty table

Comment: I would try to change the datatype, to an integer for both columns. These are just identifiers, project_id and projectid. I would also use a single name for this id, not 2 names that are almost identical.

Comment: the tables are imported from an international website, the names of the columns were put like that, project_id was an integer I changed it into a varchar

Answer (score 0):

Your code *should* work if one of the values is a number.  But neither are.  How about converting them?

```
select *
from table1 join
     table2
     on table1.projectid::numeric = table2.project_id::numeric and
        operating_unit = 'USA';
```

Sadly, having to convert on both ends precludes the use of indexes.  So an alternative is to just change one side or the other:

```
select *
from table1 join
     table2
     on '000' || table1.projectid] = table2.project_id and
        operating_unit = 'USA';
```

At least this makes it possible to use an index.

Comment: I did, project_id was first an int and I changed it to varchar because I couldn't change projectid from varchar to integer I've tried your second proposition it gives me an empty table as well